# php вывод информации о конкретном товаре

Tags: php

Здравствуйте люди добрые! Помогите студенту.
Я вывожу всю информацию о товаре через цикл:

```
$result = pg_query("SELECT r.picture, r.name as estate_name, s.name as subcategory_name, r.price, date_trunc('minute', r.datetime) 
            as datetime, r.address, r.square
            FROM realestate as r left join subcategories as s on s.id = r.subcategory_id ORDER BY r.id LIMIT $quantity OFFSET $list");

$num_result = pg_num_rows($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++) {
    $realestate_catalog = pg_fetch_array($result);

    echo " 
                        <div class=\"box-sin\">
            <div class=\"col-md-9 single-box\">
                <div class=\"box-col\">
                     <div id = \"forimage\" class=\"col-sm-7 left-side\">
                          <img class='img-responsive' src='$realestate_catalog[picture]' alt=''>
                    </div>              
                    <div class=\"col-sm-5 middle-side\">
                         <h4>$realestate_catalog[estate_name]</h4>
                         <p><span style = \"margin-right: 7%    \" class=\"bath\">Подкатегория </span>: <span class=\"two\">$realestate_catalog[subcategory_name]</span></p>
                         <p><span style = \"margin-right: 17.5%\" class=\"bath1\">Площадь </span>: <span class=\"two\"> $realestate_catalog[square]</span></p>
                         <p><span style = \"margin-right: 16%\" class=\"bath2\">Стоимость</span>: <span class=\"two\">$realestate_catalog[price]</span></p>
                         <p><span style = \"margin-right: 0.5%\" class=\"bath3\">Дата публикации </span>:<span class=\"two\">$realestate_catalog[datetime]</span></p>
                         <p><span style = \"margin-right: 24%\" class=\"bath4\">Адрес</span> : <span class=\"two\">$realestate_catalog[address]</span></p>
                        <div class=\"   right-side\">
                             <a href=\"estateredact.php\" class=\"hvr-sweep-to-right more\" target =\"parent\">Подробнее</a>     
                         </div>

                     </div>

                 <div class=\"clearfix\"> </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
                        ";
}
```

Потом, при клике на ссылку "Подробнее", перехожу на страницу, где есть контейнер для информации об одном товаре. Там вывожу переменные из нужной мне таблицы:

```
$doquery = pg_query("SELECT * FROM realestate");
    $extract = pg_fetch_array($doquery);
    $id_in = $extract['id'];
    $name_in = $extract['name'];
    $subcategory_id_in = $extract['subcategory_id'];
    $square_in = $extract['square'];
    $address_in = $extract['address'];
    $price_in = $extract['price'];
    $picture_in = $extract['picture'];
    $datetime_in = $extract['datetime'];
    $description_in = $extract['description'];
```

Информация выводится о первом товаре из базы. Мне нужно, чтобы информация выводилась о товаре, рядом с которым я кликаю ссылку "Подробнее". Как бы это все увязать. Заранее огромное спасибо тем, кто поможет.

Comment: Достал переменные которые нужны на странице, но теперь выводится последняя запись из базы. Где бы брэйк поставить?

Answer (score 1):

> [pg_fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-fetch-array.php) возвращает массив, соответствующий выбранной
> строке(записи).

Так же в документации:

> - **row**
>   Номер строки в result для выборки. Строки пронумерованы с 0 по возрастанию. Если параметр опущен или передан NULL будет выбрана
>   следующая строка.

Cледующая строка в вашем случае это первая строка в выборке.
Попробуйте так

```
 $extract = pg_fetch_array($doquery,$objectId); 
 // $objectId номер товара. Можно передовать в GET-запросе
```